# Home directory filling up on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, disk-space-utilization, home-directory

I have a dedicated ubuntu server that hosts a rails web app.  It has 2.9TB free in the home directory, which is where I host the app (for convenience sake). We host video so the home directory was filling up, so I deleted everything that was considered unnecessary.

**However**, now the home directory says it is 86% full, even though all that is on it is a web app of 10 GB.

These are the stats when I log in:

```
  System load:    2.45              Processes:           170
  Usage of /home: 81.2% of 2.70TB   Users logged in:     1
  Memory usage:   42%               IP address for eth2: 178.33.225.53
  Swap usage:     0%
```

This is what I get when I type **"du -sm * | sort -nr"** in the /home directory.

```
10369   sound
4       usera
1       lost+found
1       backup
```

And this is what I get when I type df:

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
rootfs                10403128   2034416   7844424  21% /
/dev/root             10403128   2034416   7844424  21% /
/dev                  12363412         4  12363408   1% /dev
none                   2472744       280   2472464   1% /run
none                      5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none                  12363716         0  12363716   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda2            2895674360 2350270920 399469924  86% /home
```

I am not sure what to do so any help would be really really appreciated.

Thanks

John

Comment: Try restarting any services that might have open files in `/home`.

Answer (score 1):

deleting a file doesn't release disk space whilst the file is open for reading/writing.

shut down the app, and see if the disk space reappears.

use "lsof | grep /home" if it doesn't to see what else has files open

Comment: `lsof | grep deleted` will also show open-but-deleted files.  To rapidly "zero out" a file, cat it, don't delete it:  `cat /dev/null >file` or even just `>file`.